# Change x-editable value sent to server

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I wish to change the value which x-editable sends to the server, however, wish x-editable to update the original element text as it normally does (i.e. with the value of the input).

I've come up with a solution, however, I don't believe I am doing it the correct way.  How should this be performed?

http://jsfiddle.net/oqLj9xLd/1/

```
$(function() {

    $('#name').editable({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        pk: 123,
        params:{a:1, b:2, c:3},
        send: 'never',
        validate: function (value){
            //if validate is okay, update value and continue to submit to server

            console.log(value, this, $(this));

            /*
            This doesn't work because value sent to the server doesn't change.
            Also, don't want <a> element text to be changed.
            $(this).editable('setValue', 'New value to submit', 1);

            This doesn't work since triggers validate event
            $('#name').editable('submit', {url:url, data:data});
            */

            //Is this how I need to get the options?
            var options=$(this).data('editable').options;
            var data = options.params || {};
            data.pk = 123;            
            data.value = 'new value'

            $.post(options.url, data);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change a user-friendly datetime formatted text to unix timestamp for the server. here is my (easier) solution:

```
var setupTimeOffset = $(`<div>My Time:<a>${timestampToText(setup.timeOffset)}</a></div>`);
setupEditableDateTime(setupTimeOffset.find('a'), 'timeOffset');

/* ... */

function setupEditableDateTime(control, field) {
    control.editable({
        type: 'text',
        send: 'always',
        mode: 'inline',
        url: 'ajax.php?action=updateSetup',
        params: function(params) {
            delete params.pk;
            delete params.name;
            params.field = field;
            params.value = textToTimestamp(params.value);
            return params;
        },
        success: function(response, newValue) { console.log(response); },
        error: function(response, newValue) {},
    });
}

function textToTimestamp(dateTimeText) {
    var reggie = /(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
    var dateArray = reggie.exec(dateTimeText); 
    var dateObject = new Date(
        (+dateArray[3]),
        (+dateArray[2])-1, // Careful, month starts at 0!
        (+dateArray[1]),
        (+dateArray[4]),
        (+dateArray[5]),
        (+dateArray[6])
    );
    return dateObject.getTime()/1000;
}

function timestampToText(UNIX_timestamp){
    var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var year = a.getFullYear();
    var month = ("0" + (a.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var date = ("0" + a.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var hour = ("0" + a.getHours()).slice(-2);
    var min = ("0" + a.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    var sec = ("0" + a.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    var time = date + '.' + month + '.' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec ;
    return time;
}
```

I'm also removing the pk and name field, as they are not required for my purpose.

Answer (score -1):

The `.validate()` method is purely designed for validation. You shouldn't use it as a way to modify data. Consider using [params](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable) option instead by providing it as a callback.

For example, if you want to modify field `my_field` and send `{a:1, b:2, c:3}` along with new value, you could add this code:

```
 $.fn.editable.defaults.params = function(params) {
     if (params.name === 'my_field') {
         params.value = 'new value';
     }
     params.a = 1; 
     params.b = 2; 
     // ...

     return params;
 };
```

That will allow you to change submitted data without changing user's input.

Comment: doesn't work. original values are not updated, only new values are added.